# GoogleApiClient cannot run correctly

Tags: android

I want to integrate google play services with my app.

In my main activity:

```
  googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
```

LogCat Messages :

```
com.jackryannn.playdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.jackryannn.playdemo, PID: 28594
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqN(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I don't know why it happened.I cannot find out where the problem is.

Comment: That's all what you get in the log?

Comment: please connect your android phone with android studio and debugg the app in your android phone you got the perfect log..  http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/device.html

Comment: @jackRyannn have you solved your problem?

Comment: @BhuvneshChasta how can he access the those classes if he didn't added the dependency before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this meta tag in your manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Which contain your app id

Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_1_sign_in_to_the_dev_console) for further info

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forget to add APP_ID metadata in your manifest file. You need to add the following code exactly inside the tag in the Android Manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Please make sure the meta tag is not inside the tag but tag, and use APP_ID which is 12 digits number placed right of your game title in your play game console.

Comment: i've already provided an answer for this and you didn't added any extra value for my answer

Comment: Sry dude I didn't noticed it..When I was typing this there where no answers..And Full credits to you..

Comment: Thanks for the same.